# How can I read the dynamic section of an ELF file in python

Tags: python, linux, elf, readelf

I want to get information about the dynamic section of an ELF file. Basically the same information I get using the command line:

> readelf -d elfFile

Comment: A quick Google finds https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools, have you tried it?

Comment: yes that is the tool I am currently trying to solve this task with. I can read the header of the ELF file and print the sections, but I do not get access to the sections in order to retrieve the information out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using pyelftools:

`tag = section.get_tag(n)`

gives the nth tag of a specific section